# How to trigger profiling in NodeJS at runtime?

Tags: node.js, v8, v8-profiler

We have a very stateful NodeJS based web server (Meteor) that occasionally, randomly becomes slow in production. The problem is not reproducible in any of our tests, and we don't know what's triggering it.

To diagnose this, we are using the [v8-profiler](https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-profiler) package. This lets us trigger a 10-second CPU profile and download it for offline analysis.

Despite not having received any commits in 3 years, the package used to work fairly well. It has given us compilation trouble in the past, and now it looks like it [stopped compiling](https://github.com/node-inspector/v8-profiler/issues/135) entirely, breaking our build. The build happens inside a Docker container with all versions pinned, including NodeJS and v8-profiler itself, so it's unlikely that we can fix this on our end.

I'm thinking there must be some alternative, better maintained approach. But where is it?

(Note that restarting the server with additional flags (like `--profile`) is not an option, because it destroys all the evidence of the problem.)

Comment: Did you use nodejs's native profiling ?

Comment: @ireshanpathirana If you mean what is described on https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/, no, see the last sentence in the question.

Comment: oh I get it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found there has been [v8-profiler-next](https://github.com/hyj1991/v8-profiler-next) which is a successor of v8-profiler.

I hope this works for you.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but it looks to be better maintained! Strange I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 0):

I just built a tool for this. Called ntop, so it's like "top" but for Node apps https://github.com/DVLP/ntop

The below will enable communication with the CLI. This is designed to not add any overhead when the CLI tool is not used so it can be used in production. The profiler connects/disconnects immediately only when the CLI is doing the profiling.

The app:

```js
import * as ntop from 'ntop'
ntop()
```

CLI shortcut to get a list of PIDs for convenience:

```
npx ntop
```

Outputs PIDs and additionally the command used to create the process for easier recognition.

Process detected at 12345 Details: node ./src/index.js --port 8216

```
npx ntop 12345
```

Outputs a list like "Bottom Up" in Chrome Dev Tools

- (garbage collector)     | 16.101ms |
- shift                   | 10.038ms | node:internal/priority_queue:98:7
- (anonymous)             | 9.192ms | file:///home/app/src/controllers/Server.js:24:29
- utils.bulkPreparePacket | 4.924ms | file:///home/app/src/Utils.js:91:26
- preparePacket           | 4.776ms | file:///home/app/src/Model.js:98:54
- baseGetTag              | 1.727ms | file:///home/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3104:23
- (anonymous)             | 1.702ms | evalmachine.:3:14
- isPrototype             | 1.441ms | file:///home/app/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:6441:24
- (program)               | 1.411ms |
- percolateDown           | 1.124ms | node:internal/priority_queue:40:15